# Ember AJAX route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember app that has a plugin architecture. These plugins will be able to add routes and resources to the Router.map. I load in the js files that add to the routes with AJAX calls.

The problem is that going immediately to #/some-plugin-route gives me a 404 as the app hasn't yet loaded in the route. However, going to / then #/some-plugin-route resolves just fine as the routes have been loaded.

I tried putting the AJAX calls into my Router.map call in the main app, but then it AJAXed in everything on every transition. How do I make the application load the plugins before deciding a route should redirect to the 404 page?

404 Route code:

```
window.App.NotFoundRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        var url = this.router.location.formatURL("/not-found");
        if (window.location.pathname !== url) {
            this.transitionTo("/not-found");
        }
    }
});
```

AJAX code:

```
Ember.$.getScript("/dbname/pluginId/some-plugin.js");
```

Sample Plugin:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("some-plugin-route");
});
```

Comment: what does the code to add routes with ajax look like? Perhaps using a wildcard route would be better?

Comment: could you please provide the code where you load the routes?